# Using yahoo weather Api

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, yahoo-weather-api

I am using yahoo weather api and getting result using this link:

https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22london%22)&format=json

Now I want to using this url with retrofit. So please tell me how to change the city by passing query.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would end up being something like this:

```
public interface WeatherService {
   @GET("v1/public/yql")
   Call<String> getWeather(@Query("q") String query);

}
```

Then create the object like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://query.yahooapis.com")
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

      WeatherService wService = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
```

And run it like this:

```
String query = "select * from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places(1) where text=\"Leeds\")&format=json";

Call<String> weather = wService.getWeather(query);
         try {
            Response<String> resp = weather.execute();
```

You should change the ConverterFactory to json and properly parse the weather output.

I have not tested this, just giving you an idea of how to use the Retrofit query.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well, you are looking for a way to include a given city to the url. Here is a sample code on how to do so. In the example the variable city could take any given city name.

```
var city = "london";
var query = "select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22"+ city +"%22)&format=json"
```

Update:

then you could concatenate the query to the base url like this :

```
var baseurl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query;
```